# WordPress Custom Search On Custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

I'm having troubles regarding my search. My search query runs fine, it gives the result as it should be, but the problem is it also creates a dummy product of the first searched product.

Like this image:

[image]

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'product',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'       => 'property_add_location_property_add_country',
            'value'     => $_POST['property_add_location_property_add_country'],
            'compare'   => 'IN',
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'property_add_location_property_add_state',
            'value'     => $_POST['property_add_location_property_add_state'],
            'compare'   => 'IN',
    ),
    array(
        'key'       => 'property_add_location_property_add_city',
        'value'     => $_POST['property_add_location_property_add_city'],
        'compare'   => '=',
    ),
)));
```

And this is my code which I run on `Archie-product.php`.

Please help me out, I have been doing everything to solve this for over 4 days but I can't find a solution!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: For debugging purposes, remove the `$_POST` parts and hard code values into there. Then [get the actual SQL](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/4825/12496) that was generated and run it in an SQL tool, inspect the results, and try to figure out what is causing your dummy data to appear.

Comment: Hi thanks fo your reply, I did it. There was no duplicate entry in SQL. BUt in woo-commerce im getting the error